# Why when I use bower to install jquery vs jquery#[tag] do I pull down different repositories?

Tags: jquery, bower, bower-install

```
bower install jquery
```

[image: bower install jquery]

```
bower install jquery#1.9.1
```

[image]

**And then**, how can I install jQuery 1.9.1 via bower and have the jquery distribution folder available?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [v2.1.3](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/2.1.3) & [v1.9.1](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/1.9.1) on GitHub

You see different files and folders, because some of them are ignored in the [bower.json (v2.1.3)](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.3/bower.json#L6-15)

Looks like there is no dist folder in 1.9.1. However the files are located directly in the folder.